# Module is not executing within script

Tags: python

I am attempting to write a program that loops through a bunch of files in a `.pdb` format and convert them to a `.pdbqt` format using a module called `prepare_ligand4.py`. I am fairly certain that it is correct up to the point that `prepare_ligan4.py` is called, but once it reaches this point all that happens is that the wordpad file pops up containing the code for `prepare_ligand4.py`. It should be modifying the files in the indicated directory instead. Does anyone have any advice what I should be doing? Is there a special way I need to call prepare_ligand4.py?

```
#convert pdb files to pdbqt
import os
import sys

#change directory to directory containing pdb files
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Collin\\Documents\\fragments.pdb')

#path to pdb files
path = 'C:\\Users\\Collin\\Documents\\fragments.pdb'
dirs = os.listdir(path)

#finding number of pdb files in the directory
x = len(dirs)

#loop through all files in directory and convert to pdbqt
for i in range(x):
y = dirs[i]

os.system('C:\\Python27\\MGLTools-1.5.6\\Lib\\site-packages\\AutoDockTools\\Utilities24\\prepare_ligand4.py -l y -v')
ligand_pdbqt = y[:-4]+".pdbqt"

#os.rename(os.path.join ('C:\\Users\\Collin\\Documents\\fragments_under_150.pdb',y), os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Documents\\pdbqt', ligand_pdbqt)
```

Comment: Is your script executable? Otherwise you might need to do `python script.py` rather than just `script.py`.

Comment: The line after your `for i in range(x):` is not indented. This likely causes a problem. Is that intentional (what is in your actual code), or a copy-paste error? Given that the `y=dirs[i]` should be indented, should the following two lines be indented as well?